# ArcObjects Library of Sample Scripts

Tags: arcobjects

OK, I'm still not getting help on how to code for accessing a folder. So does anyone know where they keep sample scripts for people to go look and borrow??

Comment: Have you found [ArcObjects online](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000800000003000000) yet?

Comment: What do you mean by "code to access a folder"?  What programming language are you using?  C++? C#? VB .NET?  This information will help get you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio install the ArcObjects SDK:
[ArcObjects SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/ao_home.html)

Once installed just right-click in your class and choose either "ArcGIS Snippet Finder" or "Insert Snippet..." from the context menu.

Or just use ArcObjects Online as whuber noted.